# Substrack in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writting rake task, but cant get my code to work. Is it possible to write like this?

```
Model.where('(? - begins_at)/3600 > ?', Time.now, 2).all
```

WHat am i trying to achieve is to return me list of records that are older then 2 hours

Comment: May I ask you why you want this? Can you provide a concrete example? I'm pretty sure you can do it in a different way

Comment: Every nth hour i need to do some particular task to keep data in my database up to date. I'm just not sure about syntax.

Comment: `Model.where('begins_at > ?', Time.zone.now - 1.hours).all` This will find all models where begins_at is maximum 1 hour ago from now

Comment: put your comment as answer so i could accept it. And it should be `<` instead of `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with that:

```
Model.where('begins_at < ?', Time.zone.now - 2.hours).all
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Model.where(['(? - begins_at) > ?', Time.now, 1]).all
```

As per your comment you can do like this:

```
 Model.where('begins_at < ?', Time.now - 2.hours).all
```